# Pages don't scale when exporting to PDF, this messes up printing

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, printing

I have created pagebreaks in an Excel sheet using:

```
ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add
```

After I have done this, I get print-outs in Excel that are exactly like I want them.

But if I export the Excel sheet to PDF I get one of two scenarios:

- If the content does not require scaling to fit to pages, the pages look great in PDF as well
- If the content requires scaling to fit to pages, then instead of scaling, additional page breaks are created in PDF.

The second scenario is unwanted. Is it possible to send scaled pages to PDF?

Comment: Have you tried any of the options found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25886361/3891582)?